# Oracle scheduled tasks?

Tags: java, oracle, unix, plsql, cron

I'm drawing a design for a system to do daily business functions for my company.  It will consist of a Oracle 10g database with Pl/SQL packages and a Java-based web application.  All of this is running on a Solaris 10 server.  Aside from handling transactions from the web interface, scheduled tasks need to run on the database to run calculations and load data etc.

This is a redesign of a legacy system that currently controls everything with a plethora of cron jobs. Given the task of redesigning it, would you do it differently?  I know Oracle has its own task scheduler, but the DBA argues that he would rethink using it because if the database is down or offline for some reason, it can't send alerts or log errors of any kind. The cron jobs currently have the ability to send SMS messages or emails should one of the tasks fail. Another option would be to have the web application do it somehow.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 6):

Are all the scheduled tasks related to the database?  If so, then your DBA's objection is irrelevant: you don't want to run the jobs when the database is offline for planned downtime,  and the DBA ought to have something in place to alert them if the database is down for unplanned reasons, rather than relying on a signal from a failing `cron` job.

If you have jobs which run on other parts of the architecture without touching the database then certainly an external scheduler makes sense.  There are plenty of commercial products, but if you want to go for FOSS then you probably ought to look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Having used both cron and the Oracle job scheuler - I have always found it a lot more reliable and easier to user and understand cron.  It has more things that it can do (interface with the entire OS, not just Oracle).  I would choose cron.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb for scheduled jobs is consistency.  Since you've already got a lot of infrastructure in place like alerting I'd stick with cron.